# Continue executing another thread

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, winapi

I'm currently playing with WinAPI and I have proceeded to threads. My program has `n` threads which work with each other. There is one *main* thread, which writes some data to specific memory location and waits until thread working with specific memory location processes the data. Then whole procedure repeats again, without terminating any thread.

My problem is that busy waiting for second thread wastes too much time. 
Is there any way to suspend current thread (to leave time for enother threads) or to solve this problem differently?

Please help.

Comment: WaitForMultipleObjects [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025(v=vs.85).aspx) ?

Comment: Is your main thread polling the workers?  If so, look into using a synchronisation object such as [Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682655(v=vs.85).aspx) or [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685129(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Usage(your example) [here](http://www.installsetupconfig.com/win32programming/threadprocesssynchronizationapis11_14.html), only that you have to pass TRUE in bWaitAll parameter

Comment: Thank you for semaphore advice, I found something on msdn. Please postit as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're currently polling / busy waiting in your main thread, constantly checking the state of some completion flag the worker thread will set.  As you note, this isn't desirable as you use some proportion of cpu bandwidth just waiting for the worker to complete.  In some cases, this will reduce the amount of time your worker is scheduled for, delaying its completion.

Rather that doing this, you can use a synchronisation object such as [Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682655%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to have your main thread sleep until the worker signals its completion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use synchronization objects like mutex, semaaphores events etc for synchronization and WaitForSingleObject/WaitForMultipleObject API for thread waiting.